# how to convert Expression<Action> to Action

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, action, methodinfo

Hey i was wondering if i can convert an Expression to an Action.
I need to use the Expression to get the details of the lambda expression and at the same time i need to execute it using a different method. I need to get the Expression and the actual action with just using a single parameter (either Action or Expression):
BTW i need this for Getting details on what kind of assert i did. ex(Assert.true, Assert.False)

```
public void otherMethod()
{
  SomeMethod(() => Assert.Equals("Dog","Cat"));
}



 public void SomeMethod(Expression<Action> neededAction) //or public void SomeMethod(Action neededAction)
    {       

          //i need to run the neededAction and get the details whether what assert i did and the inputs i used for the assertion

    }
```

So basically i need to run the Action and i need to get its method infos.
Thanks~

Comment: `neededAction.Compile()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `Compile()` on the expression.

```
// Compile it.
var actualNeededAction = neededAction.Compile();

// Execute it.
actualNeededAction();
```

Comment: Oh wooops. Only tackled the headline part there... I guess I'll leave this up as a partial answer at least.